# Move Fable TLC saved games to Fable Anniversary

Tags: macos, windows-7, fable, fable-anniversary

I'd like to move my Fable TLC save from OSX to Fable Anniversary on Win7.

The directory contents look identical (Autosave, Autosave.qa, Profile.bin, and some manual saves), however, then Anniversaries loads it crashes bringing up the book that holds the profiles.

If I replace the saves and not the profile, (putting the saves into an existing profile), I can see the saved games, but it crashes on loading.

Anything I can do to help do the migration? Seems pretty close already.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the save system has been completely re-done due to modern save mechanics:

> Q: Will our save game from FTLC transfer over?
>
> A: No, we've completely redone the save system for Anniversary (removing the hero and world saves). In Anniversary you can now save at any point and we have checkpoints built into quests.

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/288470/discussions/0/34095131967896117/

Comment: Thanks for finding that - hadn't found it myself when I searched. Sad, but understandable.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. It does kind of stink but I think a fresh play-through of the anniversary edition is totally worth it if you haven't done that already. They really did a top-notch job of bringing the classic feeling into the modern gaming age.